# will post_id ever change? Can I safely use post_id for custom queries?

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, customization

What are the best practices for using post_id?  Can I use this safely in my templates to call specific posts, or will these post_id's ever change?

The reason I ask is that randomly today the post_id's changed on my site, and I'm wondering what could have caused it.  It didn't mess up any of the permalinks (thankfully!) but I did have to go switch some custom queries which were calling content specifically by the post_id (specifically in some custom_post_types I've created)

So... should I use a different query to get a specific post?  The query I'm using looks like this.

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=home_feature&p=36')?>
```

Just earlier today, post_id for this post was 139 and my query was:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=home_feature&p=139')?>
```

Obviously, when the post_id changed, my query (and subsequently the custom home feature) broke. I'm just not sure what could have caused this change.. and if that means I shouldn't be using the post_id in custom queries..  Thoughts?

Comment: I don't think a post id can ever change. Its the primary key id from the posts table. So something must have been changed in your db if your post_ids got changed. That said.. its still not a good idea to use the hardcoded post_ids.

Comment: how would you reference specific pages in the hard coding (if not using post_ids)?

Comment: If its a single post, then you can use the meta key. If you need to reference multiple posts, you can use the categories.

Comment: Can you give me an example of this query?  that would be a preferable query in this case, since the post ID seems to be changing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post ID's do not change. The reason behind this is the ID column in MYSQL is the primary key for the table. It is auto incremented when a new row is added. It is improbable that a post ID would change programatically unless someone is doing something rogue in the database.

Comment: It actually just happened again on this site.  There is no other evidence of problems in the DB, but the custom query broke again for no apparent reason.  I checked, and sure enough - the about page went from p=2 to p=36.  I triple checked with my client, and no one deleted / resaved, or anything at all that should cause this change in the DB.  any thoughts at all?

Comment: could a plugin cause this possibly?  It seems to happen when I add a sidebar...  I'm at a loss

Comment: How is the custom query being made? If it's using query_posts that might be the issue. Can you show me in your question what the query looks like?

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer.  Indeed - they are not supposed to change.  We figured out this was happening when new sidebars were created.. something fishy in the functions.php code.  Sorry for the lengthy wait - I thought I already marked this answer.  Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do `<?php query_posts( 'p=36' )?>`
There shouldn't be a need to specify the post type as post ID's are supposed to be unique.

Or perhaps you could target the post by Title and get the ID from that:

```
$page = get_page_by_title('Title of Post','post');
query_posts( 'p=' . $page->ID );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you a different way to go, for sample, instead of the id, just go with the page's name, or create a meta data (custom field) with a check mark and call it.

For sure you will be safe that it breaks in the future!